# .htaccess redirect all but a few urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, iframe

So, basically, I have the following .htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /  

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/online$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://secure.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work:

(http) example.com/online is redirected to (https) secure.example.com

What I want is:

(http) example.com -> (https) secure.example.com

(http) example.com/foo/ -> (https) secure.example.com/foo/

(http) example.com/online/ -> (http) example.com/online/ (no redirect)

That's because on example.com/online I have an iframe, which src is not on HTTPS.
The other alternative is to somehow force the browser to show non-https data on the page (right now I have an empty page, because the iframe is blocked by the browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^secure\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/online [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secure\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^online(/.*)?$ http://example.com/online$1 [R=301,L]
```

First rule redirects to `https://secure` equivalent if it was `http` **OR** domain does not begin with `secure` already **AND** url is not `/online/` (`(A OR B) AND C`).

Second rule redirects `online/` to `http://example.com/online/` if it was `https` or domain begins with `secure`

Comment: hmmm.... doesn't seem to work.  probably the problem is in me...

so, let's explain further:

1. the secure subdomain has a different .htaccess file;
2. it should also work for /online/foo/ , /online/boo/ , etc
3. in order for the framework to get this, I use

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: For your first point, what's in secure htaccess ? For second point, i edited my answer to make it work. For third point, you must put my code **before** your framework rule